# Xpath for creating config file and sharepoint deployment

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint 2010 and am trying to update the config file to look like this

```
<applicationSettings>
  <Name.Library.Settings>
    <setting name="FromAddress" serializeAs="String">
      <value>tasks@munder.com</value>
    </setting>
  </Name.Library.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

by deploying a feature with the following code

```
  ,new ModificationEntry(
      "applicationSettings/Name.Library.Settings"
       ,"configuration/applicationSettings"
       ,"<Name.Library.Settings/>" 
       ,SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode 
       ,true) 
  ,new ModificationEntry(
       "applicationSettings/Name.Library.Settingsname='IsSharepointDeployed']"
       ,"configuration/applicationSettings/Name.Library.Settings"
       ,"<setting name='IsSharepointDeployed' serializeAs='String' />" 
       ,SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode 
       ,true)
```

When I do this I'm getting the following error "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Expression must evaluate to a node-set."

I belive this is telling me that my xpath query is wrong.  It is configuration/applicationSettings/Name.Library.Settings

Any ideas what may be wrong with it?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with XPath. It isn't clear what should be achieved.

Comment: Well the method ModificationEntry takes a simple xPath as one of its arguments, so there is a possible connection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solves all of your problem but:

```
"applicationSettings/Name.Library.Settings[@name='IsSharepointDeployed']"
```

Might help.